# auto-populate field 2 based on field 1 in Oracle APEX4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have two fields name's as Monthly salary , annual salary.
i need to write a code in oracle apex so that if i enter a monthly salary, annual salary field should auto populate based on the monthly salary added.

Comment: if user types 15000 in monthly salary, then 15000*12=180000, 180000 value should be aut-opopulate to annual salary

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way would be to create a dynamic action, wich triggers every time, when there is a change in your first field. As action you choose JavaScript and write the function and populate the second field with the result of the function.

```
var Field1 document.getElementById('PX_FIELD1').value;
var Field2 = Field1*12;
document.getElementById('PX_FIELD2').value=Field2;
```

This is just an example, but it shows you how you can read and write from a field with javascript.

Comment: Use $v('PX_FIELD1') function to get value of the item.